# Problems with Bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small issue with the bootstrap grid system.

It's a bit difficult to explain my problem, so I added a picture to prove my issue. This issue happens when I add pictures on the second line (when the first line is full

[image]

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/29591/screenshots/1095922/flat_icons_1x.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/24078/screenshots/1096340/whale.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/141038/screenshots/1095723/cfrej_1x.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/86429/screenshots/1095840/happywoodcutter_ipad_sounas_1x.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/86429/screenshots/1095840/happywoodcutter_ipad_sounas_1x.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A row in Bootstrap equals to 12 columns. You are trying to insert 15 columns in a 12 column row (5 divs, each spanning on 3 columns).

This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="portfolio-thumb span3">
     <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/29591/screenshots/1095922/flat_icons_1x.png">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-thumb span3">
     <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/24078/screenshots/1096340/whale.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-thumb span3">
     <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/141038/screenshots/1095723/cfrej_1x.png">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-thumb span3">
     <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/86429/screenshots/1095840/happywoodcutter_ipad_sounas_1x.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="portfolio-thumb span3">
     <img src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/86429/screenshots/1095840/happywoodcutter_ipad_sounas_1x.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html.

Basically, Bootstrap's grid system is based on 12 columns. Each `<div class="row-fluid">` should represent one row and not overflow to the next line. So the problem in your markup is that you have 15 columns in one row.

You can fix it by closing the `row-fluid` div and opening a new one after the 4th image (12 columns - 4 times `span3`).